# How do I add a new .swift file to an Xcode static lib project that already contains .c so that func in new file can be called by a Swift app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I created an Xcode static lib project with .c files and it works.

I used Xcode "new file" to add a new .swift file that contains Swift "func health_algo_test()" to my static lib but build of my app project that contains lib can't find health_algo_test() and gets build error:

> "Cannot find 'health_algo_test' in scope".

viewcontroller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    health_algo_test() //!!!
    . . .
}
```

interface.swift:

```
import Foundation

import UIKit
import os
    
func health_algo_test()
{
    print("health_algo_test...")
}
```

Contents of .a shown by running nm...........

Contents of lib's .a output:
`$ nm Debug-iphoneos/libproject_lib.a | grep health

0000000000000000 T _$s33project_libc16health_algo_testyyF

STATIC LIB PROJECT ................
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remember to add the new file to any targets that you want to include it.

Select the file in the project navigator (View->Navigators->Project), and then take a look at the file inspector (View->Inspectors->File). You'll see a checklist there containing a list of all the targets in your project; make sure that there's a check mark next to the target you're trying to build, indicating that the new file will be included in that target.

Also, since you're building a library and the code that calls `health_algo_test()` is outside the library, you'll need to mark that function (and any others that clients should be able to call) `public`, e.g.:

```
public func health_algo_test()
{
    print("health_algo_test...")
}
```

Comment: Didn't fix it.  New .swift file was already set for target.  I added screen shot of lib project.

Comment: @DougNull See my updated answer for another possible solution. Good luck.